# How can i make a if statement inside a while loop to perform certain actions only on certain lines?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a simple bash script launched in sh that allows me to create a new output file starting from an input file and keeping each line starting with ">" in its position, while for every line that does not satisfy this requirement, it must delete every third character and then hanging it in the new file.

input file:

```
>0197_16S  
-AAAAACATGTCCTCTTGTTTATA-----TNTGAGGTTTGACCTGCCCTATG--A---  
>0688_16S    
-----ACATCTTCTCTTGAGTTAT-----TTTGAGATATGACCTGCCCAATG--A-T-  
.  
.  
.  
.
```

sh script:

```
while IFS= read line; do  
if [ "$line" = ">"* ]; then echo "$line" >> output.txt  
else
var=$(echo "$line" | awk -vFS= '{for (i = 1; i <=NF; i+3) {printf $i(i+1)} printf "\n"}');  
echo "$var" >> output.txt  
fi;  
done <foo.txt
```

the else statement seems to work, however the condition of the if is never verified, eliminating every third character also from the lines that begin with the character ">".

actual output:

```
>09716  
-AAACAGTCTTTTTAT----NTAGTTGACTCCTAG-A--  
>08816
----CACTCTTTAGTA----TTAGTAGACTCCAAG-A--  
.  
.  
.
```

expected output:

```
>0197_16S  
-AAACAGTCTTTTTAT----NTAGTTGACTCCTAG-A--  
>0688_16S  
----CACTCTTTAGTA----TTAGTAGACTCCAAG-A--  
.  
.  
.
```

Comment: You have to use `[[ ... ]]` for pattern matching.

Comment: with    [[ ... ]]  i've this error message:    script1.sh: 5: script1.sh: [[: not found

Comment: Then you aren't actually using `bash`. Do you have `#!/bin/sh` at the top of your script? Change it to `#!/bin/bash`. If you are running your script with `sh script`, change it to `bash script`.

Comment: it works, thank you too! i'm pretty new in scripting and i usualy run them in sh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try avoiding a while-loop.

Without the condition `keeping each line starting with ">" in its first position` you can do

```
sed -r  's/(..)./\1/g' foo.txt
```

Add a condition for the lines with `>` can be done by changing all lines that don't match

```
sed -r  '/^>/ !s/(..)./\1/g' foo.txt
```

Or with `awk`:

```
awk '/^>/ {print;next} {print gensub(/(..)./,"\\1", "g")}' foo.txt
```